# Pattern Matching in Confluent.net

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, .net-core-3.1

So, I have a situation where I am suppose to match the pattern of the topics that I am subscribing to. The structure of my topics is 3-part "part1.part2.part3" so for e.g. DbServerName.Domain.DbTableName.
Now according to this post https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/245 if I prefix my topic name with a "^" it should work.

So
`consumer.Subscribe("^")` work fine --give all the topics 
`consumer.Subscribe("^DbServerName.public.DbTableName")` also works fine.

but if I want to match my topics against just DbTableName irrespective of whatever DbserverName and domain might be it doesn't work

So
`consumer.Subscribe("^.^.tableName")` doesn't work
`consumer.Subscribe("^tablename")` also doesn't work.

any suggestion on how to achieve this functionality would be much appreciated. cheers !!

Comment: How about `^.*tablename`? As in, `^` turns on regex, so you continue to type a regex pattern?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes!! that works perfectly fine. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, `^` is a feature toggle, so the pattern would be

```
"^" + ".*tablename"
```

Comment: would this work with Ksql Streams as well ?because it give me unknown broker exception

Comment: KSQL doesn't use .NET, so no. And I don't think a stream can be created from multiple topics... Also "unknown broker" would be before the consumer is established

Comment: I joined (inner join) couple of topics to produce a stream, now the problem is that it can be from different sources (db servers), and to subscribe to those stream I would explicitly need to mention all db server names. And yes the exception occurs while subscribing to the consumer.

Comment: Right, you would need one `CREATE STREAM` per topic (which contains server name  + table name). You cannot use a regex for that

Comment: So in that case ill have to maintain the list of all the Streams. I was hoping the .net library would support it considering its already there for topics. Anyways thanks for your help ..cheers !!

Comment: You could use the AdminClient to list all topics matching a regex, then use KSQL REST API to create all the streams.